# How to make an async sleep execution in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sleep

This could be done with a cronjob, but since I have not yet changed over to a provider with a plan including the same, I came up with what I think might be a possible workaround to my objective, if not even an actually better solution.
Scope: This is a messenger system where you want that other users are made aware whenever a user logs off. This is done easily for situations where the user decides to logoff in the application, but if the users wifi goes down, for instance, obviously the app won´t be able to tell the other users that he´s no longer online. 
Each 5 secs, there´s a check done by the app for new messages, which also updates a mysql with a current timestamp for each user. So I thought that if the php script that is called by the app each 5 seconds checks for whether if the timestamp in the sql table at the time the php script is called is the same 10 seconds later, then the other users will be told that he´s gone offline.
So this is what I did, at the end of the script:

```
$sql =$conn->prepare ("SELECT time FROM Users WHERE username = ? limit 1");
$sql->execute(array($usernametmp));  
$oldtime = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
sleep(10);
$sql =$conn->prepare ("SELECT time FROM Users WHERE username = ? limit 1");
$sql->execute(array($usernametmp));  
$newtime = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
if ($oldtime == $newtime) 
{
(here´s where the other users are being informed
....
```

But sadly all the code in the whole php script is not executed till after the 10 seconds sleep. What I want is that all code before the sleep command gets executed, and 10 secs later, the above gets fired. 
Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Comment: if you have a front-end. id have js ping the backend on a set interval as a keep-awake. if you actually wanted async php, threads or a queueing system are what you should look into.

Comment: Thanks,I guess I rather just do this once I´ve migrated to a VPS and see what options I have there. I came up with the below - trying both system and exec, but they get totally ignored with no error or anything so I think there´s a way that my host blocks for running async operations:
    $sql =$conn->prepare ("SELECT time FROM Users WHERE 
    username = ? limit 1");
    $sql->execute(array($usernametmp));  
    $oldtime = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    system("php offlinechk.php?oldtime=$oldtime &");
    exec("php offlinechk.php?oldtime=$oldtime &");

offlinechk = code in post 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I came up with a decent workaround:

Every time client checks for new messages, the new timestamp added for this user in the mysql table is also sent to the client.
The timestamp is immidiately sent to another php script from the client, which sleeps for 10 secs and then checks if the timestamp is identical to the one in the mysql db. If this is the case, the status of the client is changed to offline because during those 10 seconds, there should have been an update to the timestamp in the table - unless the client went offline.